# Set Null value in JSON path expressions

Tags: jmeter

My JSON path expression in JSON Extractor is

```
$.data.Transactions.[?(@.transactionId=='${transId}')].status
```

If this expression is not returning any result I want to assign `NULL` to the variable

Answer (score 0):

Set [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)'s `Default Values` as NULL

> Default Values
>   Semi-colon separated default values if JSON-PATH expressions do not return any result(must match number of variables)s
>   Semi-colon separated default values if JSON-PATH expressions do not return any result(must match number of variables)